# Best .NET Framework compression class?

Tags: c#, compression

Yes, I know GZipStream or DeflateStream is the common ones in .NET Framework which handle compression/decompression.

I wish to have compress/decompress functions in my program, but

1. I wish a .NET Framework C# one, not a 3rd party open source. I can't use because of those copyright restrictions in my program.
2. GZipStream and DeflateStream are not so good. for e.g., GZipStream compress a file to 480KB while 7Zip compress the same file to the size of 57KB.

Does Microsoft have other good compression methods???

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.

Can I ask whether DeflateStream is using Huffman coding?

Comment: Both `DeflateStream` and `GZipStream` use a combination of the LZ77 algorithm and Huffman coding (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx). `Deflate` is the pure compression algorithm, while `GZipStream` includes a CRC checksum and *could* be extended by writing different compression algorithms (The current .net framework just implements that one compression algorithm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GZipStream and DeflateStream are specifically intended for compressed *streams*, not general compression of files for storage.

Other than those classes, compression is not built into .NET. If you want high-quality compression you will have to go to a third party library. Check out http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html for an open-source 7zip library.

Comment: The web page states that "LZMA SDK is placed in the public domain" that should mean that it is free to use however you like, doesn´t it?

Comment: Dave put it in the right direction, but Stefan gave the link to the ready to use .Net implementation of the 7zip algorithm (which is lzma).

Comment: Absolutely, free to all.  The OP says he doesn't want "3rd party open source."  If cost is not the concern, I'm not sure what is.

Comment: Just wanted to share with future people; C# has the ZipArchive class. If used with optimal compression option you might also get good results.

Answer (score 2):

There is a managed wrapper for 7zip. The license is LGPL so you can use it in closed source projects. I do not know if this fits your license requirements as you did not state them.

http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any statistics regarding compression rates, but I'd been using the [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) library for years with much success.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I try to compress like recursive data, is funny. Check my example:

```
private byte[] CompressWithLevels(byte[] data)
{
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using(GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            gz.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I try to Compress a file too big, for example:

```
string path = @"c:\test.bin";
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
byte[] level1 = CompressWithLevels(buffer);
byte[] level2 = CompressWithLevels(level1);
```

Check the size of buffer, level1 and level2.
buffer size is 77683, level1 = 57354 and level2 = 8202...

buffer is 100%, then:
57354 is 73,83%
8202 is 10,55%
so funny.

Comment: that is funny... does it go backwards? what's the limit?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the open source ZLib (http://www.zlib.net/) with PInvoke, or use a wrapper for it (I've used zlib.net - http://www.componentace.com/zlib_.NET.htm - but I believe it had some bugs).
it's less convenient than managed libraries, but more efficient than DeflateStream/GZipStream (which are the same except for an extra CRC in GZipStream).